# How to get address of existing Ray redis cluster?

Tags: ray

Im writing a flask app that uses Ray. Im trying to just run ray.init() once when the app is started up and then reference that cluster when actually using ray in other files. From the docs it looks like I need to run ray.init(address="") before I can use ray but how do I programmatically get or pass the existing ray cluster's address after running ray.init() the first time? Also, if this is not the right approach in general, please recommend a better design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went with is

`if ray.is_initialized() == False: 
   ray.init()`

Answer (score 0):

`ray.init(address="auto")` should work. If you need to run `ray.init` "after running init the first time", you can run `ray.shutdown()` and then `ray.init(address="auto")`.

Comment: Since ray takes several seconds to initialize I would like to minimize impact to performance by keeping the same ray cluster alive and just connecting to it whenever there's a new request to my app. I also want to avoid reloading imported modules. However, I would want to clear any outputs saved to memory between requests.

Comment: The solution I went with is `if ray.is_initialized() == False:
    ray.init()`